# How to configure 'entityCacheStrategies' in spring4.3.x

Tags: caching, spring-4, hibernate-5.x

I am migrating from spring3.x to spring4.3.x. I am using org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean in bean creation as follows

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.person.domain.Person</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:com/example/person/domain/Person.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${cache.providerClass}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.dogpilePrevention">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.servers">${cache.memcached.servers}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.keyStrategy">com.example.memcached.ExampleCacheStringKeyStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.deviceAttributeDao.keyStrategy">com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.HashCodeKeyStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.memcached.EncodingDao.keyStrategy">com.googlecode.hibernate.memcached.HashCodeKeyStrategy</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="entityCacheStrategies">
        <props>
            <prop key="com.example.person.domain.TestAttribute">read-write,_domain</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'entityCacheStrategies' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'entityCacheStrategies' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:242)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
... 66 more
```

I am using spring-4.3.0.RELEASE. The LocalSessionFactoryBean doesn't have setter for entityCacheStrategies. Any idea how to support this in spring4.3.x?

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `entityCacheStrategies/setEntityCacheStrategies()` has been deprecated in hibernate 5. A probable alternative from `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration : setCacheConcurrencyStrategy(String clazz, String concurrencyStrategy)`is also no longer in use.

But if you're open to configuring the cache using hibernate annotations library, then try [this approach](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CacheConcurrencyStrategy.html) which makes the use of `CacheConcurrencyStrategy`enumerator.
You can apply appropriate `Concurrency` strategy at `Entity` level.

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Clazz{..}
```

Please find more usages of `CacheConcurrencyStrategy` in the [dev guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html).